# How can I save a modified image in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I'm trying to save a new photo in database which is modified, I have my javascript ( darkroomjs) for cropping photos, but the new photo doesn't save in database. I'd like to save my new photo instead of the original photo.

```php
$profile_images = $request['profilefiles'];
$profile_images = explode(";;", $profile_images);
array_shift($profile_images);
$image = "";

foreach ($profile_images as $key => $value) {
    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $value);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];
    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);

    $destinationPath = public_path('images/model/');
    $hardPath = str_random(10) . '.' . $image_type;
    $filename = $destinationPath . $hardPath;
    file_put_contents($filename, $image_base64);

    $image = $hardPath;
}

$model->title = $request['title'];
$model->slug = Slugify::slugify($request['title']);
$model->phone = $request['phone'];
$model->external_link = $request['external_link'];
$model->email = $request['email'];
$model->description = $request['description'];
$model->category = $request['category'];
$model->instagram = $request['instagram'];
$model->category_id = $request['category_id'];
$model->badges_id = $request['badges_id'];
$model->height = $request['height'];
$model->boost = $request['boost'];
$model->waist = $request['waist'];
$model->hips = $request['hips'];
$model->shoes = $request['shoes'];
$model->hair = $request['hair'];
$model->eyes = $request['eyes'];
$model->dress = $request['dress'];
$model->publish = $publish;
$model->age = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request['dob']));
$model->metatitle = $request['title'];
$model->metadescription = substr(strip_tags($request['description']), 0, 160);

if ($image != "") {
    var_dump($image);
    $model->image = $image;
}
$model->upload_pdf = $upload_pdf;
$model->save();
```

Comment: Are you uploading multiple images or single image?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at either http://image.intervention.io/ or https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/introduction

Comment: A single image with id profileImg. I have multiple  models with one picture for each.And, in edit-model, I have a single image and I need to save the modified image( with darkroom.js ) instead of the original picture generated from database.

Comment: I have another function " drag&drop " ( the first function ' profilefiles ') who upload and switch the original photo with another and save it to image/. I'd like to use something like that for my function if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Above image shows callback to get edited image.

1)  You can save this file somewhere in temp folder at server by making ajax call to server.

2) During you save other fields(POST request). You can simply move file from temp folder to your images folder and file name into DB.

Ref : https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs

Comment: Can you give me an example please? I'm not sure that I understand exactly. @Waleed Khan

Comment: this is my darkroomjs now : https://github.com/andreixfr/andrei/blob/master/darkroomjs

Comment: Here is link which explain basics, I hope it helps - https://www.screencast.com/t/I1hayI2Fo

Comment: I saw that in console I have something like that after cropping : <img src="data:image/png;base64, and a lot of code after.  Thank you for your picture.  But I dont know how i should write in code that I want to save it to temp. I also saw this : https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs/issues/93 , but I dont know how to write this.

Comment: https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs#building
https://github.com/MattKetmo/darkroomjs#usage

Answer (score 0):

You can simply

```
$path = Storage::put('images/model', $image_base64);
```

This will create you a unique name and save it in your `storage/app` rather than public (which is what you need to do rather than saving in `public/`  directory itself).